Fuzzy contours on MapLibre GL JS sprites
I am using sprites in a MapLibre GL JS map. Unfortunately the contours of the sprites are fuzzy. This is not so noticeable with small symbols, but with larger ones it no longer looks good. I created the sprites with spritezero and they are available in normal and double resolution.
 
Thats the sprite.json section for the purple square:
 "quadrat": {
    "height": 171,
    "pixelRatio": 1,
    "width": 171,
    "x": 512,
    "y": 512
  }

I would say the resolution is high enough, isn't it?
Here is an example from Komoot, where the contours are not quite sharp either:

Do you know how I can avoid or improve this effect? Is the problem in the rendering by MapLibre or can I change something when creating the sprites?

If it should be of interest to anyone else, I think I solved the issue:
The resolution of the individual sprites should correspond approximately to the target resolution in which the sprite is also rendered. After reducing the resolution, the contours are significantly sharper than if the resolution was previously too high and the sprite size was reduced using the image-size property.

